# Waveshare 2.9inch_Touch_e-Paper_HAT: Getting Demo to work

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I thought I just share m findings if anybody else has bought the same e-paper touch display and struggles to start the demo on a raspberry pi (python).

In my case I followed the wiki page:
https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/2.9inch_Touch_e-Paper_HAT

But then there was no "main.py" to start, so I figured i tried the existing file "`TP2in9_test.py`".

After doing "`chmod -x TP2in9_test.py`" I started the file with
`sudo python3 TP2in9_test.py` but got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Touch_e-Paper_Code/python/examples/TP2in9_test.py", line 14, in <module>
    from TP_lib import weather_2in9_V2
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/waveshare_ETP-0.0.0-py3.9.egg/TP_lib/weather_2in9_V2.py", line 60, in <module>
    font12 = ImageFont.truetype(os.path.join(fontdir, 'Font.ttc'), 12)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 852, in truetype
    return freetype(font)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 849, in freetype
    return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 209, in __init__
    self.font = core.getfont(
OSError: cannot open resource
```

I then commented out both lines that referenced the "weather" script/function, that is `lines 14` and `112`.

After that the display demo works and even the weather part is showing up, nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: Comment out both lines that referenced the "weather" script/function,
that is lines 14 and 112.